# docker swarm - etcd cluster is unavailable or misconfigured

Tags: docker, etcd, docker-swarm

I'm trying to get started with docker swarm using etcd for the [discovery backend](https://docs.docker.com/swarm/discovery/). My etcd server is at etcd.programster.org (10.1.0.44) whilst my docker node is at swarm1.programster.org (10.1.0.47). All machines are running on Virtualbox instances on my local network (10.1.0.x).

I manage to get my etcd server running with the following:

```
MY_IP="10.1.0.44"

./etcd \
-name infra0 \
-initial-advertise-peer-urls http://$MY_IP:2380 \
-listen-peer-urls="http://0.0.0.0:2380,http://0.0.0.0:7001" \
-listen-client-urls="http://0.0.0.0:2379,http://0.0.0.0:4001" \
-advertise-client-urls="http://$MY_IP:2379" \
-initial-cluster-token etcd-cluster-1 \
-initial-cluster infra0=http://$MY_IP:2380 \
-initial-cluster-state new
```

I can set and retrieve key values from swarm1.programster.org just fine with curl and etcd.

```
# setting key with etcdctl
./etcdctl --peers http://etcd.programster.org:4001 set etc://etcd.programster.org/mykey "test"

# setting key with curl
curl -L \
http://etcd.programster.org:4001/v2/keys/mykey \
-XPUT -d value="test"

# retrieving key with etcdctl
./etcdctl --peers http://etcd.programster.org:4001 get etc://etcd.programster.org/mykey

# retrieving key with curl
curl -L http://etcd.programster.org:4001/v2/keys/mykey
```

However, whenever I run a swarm based command such as:

```
docker run swarm list etcd://10.1.0.44/
```

or

```
docker run swarm join --advertise=10.1.0.47:2375 etcd://10.1.0.44/
```

I always get the following error message:

```
[timestamp] client: etcd cluster is unavailable or misconfigured
```

Have I configured my etcd server incorrectly or perhaps there is a networking configuration that I need to perform on the docker node first? I have not performed any TLS authentication yet for simplicity but perhaps swarm will not work without this?

### Context

- All machines are running Debian 8 (3.16.0-4-amd64). Also tested with Ubuntu 14.04 for swarm1.programster.org.
- Docker version 1.9.1, build a34a1d5
- etcd version 2.2.2

Comment: Would https://github.com/coreos/flannel/issues/345#issuecomment-149434419 help?

Comment: Did you start your docker daemon by setting the flags `--cluster-advertise` and `--cluster-store` ?

Comment: @M.Auzias I added `DOCKER_OPTS="--cluster-store=consul://10.1.0.44:8500 --cluster-advertise=eth0:2376"` to my `/etc/default/docker` file of swarm1.programster.org and ran `sudo service docker restart` and still no luck. Based my config on [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/get-started-overlay/).

Comment: @Programster what does `ps aux|grep docker` and `docker info` output? If you are seeking for multi-host networking I suggest you to take a look at this step-by-step tutorial: https://www.auzias.net/en/docker-network-multihost/ (I'm planning on adding it to the Swarm documentation -- as accepted by Moxie via twitter), in the meanwhile, I think (and hope) you may find some useful info.

Comment: @M.Auzias thanks. Ill dig through there and will try getting a swarm going using static files first to see if that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try including the port number like this:

```
docker run swarm join --advertise=10.1.0.47:2375 etcd://10.1.0.44:2379/swarm
```

I had the same issue and I assumed docker would intelligently infer the port number from "etcd://" - I was wrong.

Comment: Kicking myself for not thinking of such a simple thing.